# Creating Maven project in Eclipse Kepler EE

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am completely new to Maven. I am using Eclipse Kepler EE edition. I want to create a Maven project and convert it into a Java EE project. I need a step-by-step explanation of the process. I would prefer if I didn't have to use the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: See this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uv9tXFrTLtI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I want to create a Maven project and convert it into a Java EE project.`

You can work in either way. Lets look at the possibilities

1. Create a new project (Dynamic web project) and add any facets you want in the JEE project. **How To :** Once project is setup, simply right click on the *project* --> *Configure* --> *convert to maven project* , specify the artifactID along with the groupID and you are done !
2. Instead of making a dynamic project, just setup a blank maven project first and then add the facets afterwards. **How To :** In Eclipse, *New Project* --> *maven project* --> *Blank project ( skip archetype selection )* , specify groupdID and artifactID and you're done. After wards just add the facets once the project is setup by righ-clicking the newly created maven project --> *Properties* --> *facets*
3. Lastly you can use archetypes. Archetypes are re-build/configured maven projects that can be used directly since they come pre-configured with whole set of jars, facets and build path entries. Take a look into the list [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) . **How To :** In eclipse *New project* --> *New maven project* --> *archetype* --> specify name of archetype and voila! You're done !

Comment: Can you make a new Question post and tag me in there? We'll look at it there @JeroenBollen

Answer (score 1):

`File --> New --> other --> J2EE --> WHATEVER J2EE Type of Project you want`

After that you Right-Click the project and goto `Configure -> Convert to maven project`

You can also use `Configure -> Convert to Faceted form` and activate the facets you want for your J2EE Project from the project properties.

`Properties -> Project Facets`

I hope this will get you started.

Comment: That created `pom.xml`. But then what is the `File -> New -> Maven Project` about? What does that do?

Comment: It does the same but you will create a plain java project. With that you have to add the J2EE capabilities by hand (Convert to faceted form).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by installing the Eclipse plugin [Maven Integration for WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/). The plugin is a good starting point. Some understanding on Maven topics like plugins, goals would help you in a great way for creating a Maven project from scratch. Have a look at the [getting started guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

Since you are looking for a Java EE project I am guessing you are looking to generate an EAR file for which you can use this [Apache Maven EAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/)