# Export Library which uses Lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl, buildpath

I wrote a small OpenGL library for private use. 
It is based on Lwjgl. I am programming with eclipse. 
Now I want to export this library to have one JarFile, which 
I can add to the build path of a project and the user can
only use the library and not lwjgl. So I want to keep lwjgl and the 
native files in the build path but export it with my library as one jar.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: How are you currently building and packaging your project? Will [`maven`](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_use_in_Maven) work for you?

Comment: im not building or packagin it now. i just have this package with my lib in a project, to which lwjgl is binded to. I'll look on maven, i neither used it nor know what it is.. but thank you

Comment: So in your project, do you have at least a `lib` folder containing the JAR of `lwjgl`, and another `src` folder containing your Java codes?

Comment: no i havent, but i could do so. i just shuold change the buildpath then?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to help manage your project life cycle. While there are many other tools out there, maven has been one of the more widely used so if you encountered any difficulties, it won't be hard to find solutions.

Maven can be used to build and package your artifacts, and manage your dependencies (in this case `lwjgl` and other dependencies `lwjgl` needs). Since you are already using Eclipse, you can easily use it to create a maven project. (Refer this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609700/creating-maven-project-in-eclipse-kepler-ee) for guidance). From there, Eclipse will help to manage all your build/class paths.

***Project Structure***

After you create your maven project in Eclipse, you will see that under the project root folder, there is at least:

1. a [`pom.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file. Maven uses this file to determine anything and everything about your project including dependencies.
2. a `src/main` folder. This is where you will keep all your Java source codes.
3. a `src/test` folder. This is where you will keep all your test codes.

***Managing Your Dependencies***

The next step involves modifying your `pom.xml` to specify `lwjgl` as a dependency. To do so, add the following dependency configuration to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that this `<dependency>` configuration should be added to a parent `<dependencies>` section.

This will download the main `lwjgl.jar` (version 2.9.1) and the natives for Windows, Linux and Mac OSX from the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.lwjgl.lwjgl%7Clwjgl%7C2.9.1%7Cjar) into your project (so you don't have to manage it manually, say in a separate `lib` folder).

***Export Your Project As A JAR***

If all went well, you will be able to build your project by navigating to your project root from command line (you can do this in Eclipse too), and issue the command

`mvn clean install`

which will build your Java codes, execute your unit tests suite (if any), download any dependencies specified in your `pom.xml`, and generate a JAR file named after your project in the `target` folder.

To verify, unzip the JAR file and you should be able to find `lwjgl.jar` along with any other dependencies in one of the folders.

Hope this will get you started.

EDIT:

***Building Your Project***

If your `target` folder remains empty after executing `mvn clean install`, try include this build plugin configuration in your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: its too late now.. ill look tomorow on this ^^ thank you

Comment: mh.. no.
I think i didnt really understand how i can do this.
I created a maven project in eclipse. in the src folder i put my library packages with the code. Then i added the dependencie entry, this worked, the lwjgl libs and natives were added to the project. Then.. i clicked right and run as "maven clean" and "maven install".. but now jar file appeared... right click and export didnt work though.

Comment: @T_01 That sounds right. Once you got the JAR file in the `target` folder, you can unzip it, then you should be able to see all the `.class` files of your codes and the `lwjgl` library. They are usually stored in sub-folders so you may have to search around.

Comment: oo.. not "now jar file appeared.." NO jar file appeared.. thats the point :D

Comment: @T_01 If you are viewing it from within eclipse, you may have to refresh your project space. Then you should see a `target` folder after you run `maven install`.

Comment: @T_01 I have added configuration to the maven compiler plugin to be added to your `pom.xml`. It shouldn't be necessary but give it a try.